/var/log/lastlog is huge - how to logrotate it
On my filesystem, the file /var/log/lastlog is huge
ll /var/log/lastlog

-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 494536286056 May 28 17:27 /var/log/lastlog

is there a Ubuntu-native way to logrotate it?

from lastlog documentation

NOTE         top
The lastlog file is a database which contains info on the last
login of each user. You should not rotate it. It is a sparse
file, so its size on the disk is usually much smaller than the
one shown by "ls -l" (which can indicate a really big file if you
have in passwd users with a high UID). You can display its real
size with "ls -s".

ls -s /var/log/lastlog


116 /var/log/lastlog


actually returns only 116 bytes.
